# ошибка - Unsupported method: GradleProject.getProjectDirectory()

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Знатоки, нужна ваша помощь. Нашел старый проект при открытии все нормально но вылазит ошибка. При этом сам градл установлен 3.5.3 а в этом проекте 1.2.3. прописывал новый, ничего не помогло. к слову вроект года так 2015го, делался на актуальной на тот момент AS. Сейчас AS новая.
ошибка при 1.2.3
[image: ошибка при 1.2.3]

ошибка при 3.5.3
[image: ошибка при 3.5.3]

модуль ниже

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
    compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1251' //���������
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ooo.test"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.9.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.2.0.jar')
}
```

проджект

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы пробовали добавить другие репозитории для версии 3.5.3?
Попробуйте так:
repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

Проверил на jcenter - там нет gradle версии старше 2.5.0

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov сделал как Вы сказали, теперь ошибка ERROR: Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container.

Comment: сейчас чуть подробнее напишу, 3 минуты

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста текст ошибке текстом а не изображениями :)

Comment: @Andrew Сорри уже поправили все, обратно окатывать уже не стану)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка для версии gradle 3.5.3 появляется из-за того, что на jcenter нет gradle версии выше 2.5.0
Посмотреть можно [тут](https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/)

Для исправления:

В project вместо

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

Вставляем

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

И вместо

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Соответственно

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Вроде должно заработать.

P.s. Полагаю, нажатие на кнопку "Add Google Maven repository and sync project" в ошибке для 3.5.3 так же помогло бы)

Comment: Вы мой спаситель. Да почти полный расклад написали и в первый раз. Еще в чем был косяк, так в том, что в старой версии проекта был прописан https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip, а в новой прописал https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip. и вуаля... СПАСИБО!!!